# Display next and previous in JTextArea with JButtons using a ListIterator

Tags: java, swing, iterator

Im creating a small GUI ArrayList programme using a ListIterator which display the Strings of the ArrayList one at a time in a TextArea using JButtons which allow the user to go next and previous. Its working in a strange way though as the previous button only works when the GUI is started and then takes multiple clicks to go between elements. Next also only works once previous has hit the last element. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NextAndPrevious extends JFrame{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    ListIterator<String> iterator = (ListIterator<String>) list.listIterator();


public NextAndPrevious() {
     
     JButton next,previous;
     JTextArea display;
     
     iterator.add("Jim");
     iterator.add("Bob");
     iterator.add("Karl");
//GUI
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

next = new JButton("Next");
this.add(next,BorderLayout.EAST);

previous = new JButton("Previous");
this.add(previous,BorderLayout.WEST);

display = new JTextArea();
this.add(display,BorderLayout.CENTER);

//Button for next in list
next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            display.setText(iterator.next());
        }
    }
}
);
//Button for previous in list
previous.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
            display.setText(iterator.previous());

}
    }
    });
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    NextAndPrevious b = new NextAndPrevious();
    b.setSize(400, 400);
    b.setVisible(true);
    b.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
}
}
```

Comment: a) read the api doc of ListIterator (note where the cursor is after adding to an empty list) b) compare the logic of your code in the next/previous handler (hint: while vs if)

Comment: Yes gave it another read there were you pointed out. I have managed to get it mostly working only issue left is it still requires multiple button clicks but I will post the solution now.

Comment: A different approach would be to keep an "index" variable to track which item is currently displ.ayed. Then when you go forward you can increment this variable and get the item from the ArrayList. And decrement when you go backwards. An iterator it typically used when you want to look through the entire list at one time in one direction.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working. However still sometimes requires 2 button clicks to get next and previous but here is what I changed.

Added the Strings to the ArrayList instead of listIterator and then moved the the initialize.

```
 list.add("Jim");
     list.add("Bob");
     list.add("Karl");
     iterator =list.listIterator();
```

Then simply just changed my while to an if for next

```
              if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    display.setText(iterator.next());
                }
```

Apologies for if this was a poor solution and question I had just been struggling on this for hours and was reading through the api and just couldnt figure it out till now. Though I hope if someone is stuck on a similar problem as me this helps somewhat.

Comment: *still sometimes requires 2 button clicks* - because the iterator is pointing at the "next" value. So to go to the previous you need to reset the pointer to the start of the current item and then a second call to go the the previous. So every change of direction will require two clicks. To solve the problem you would need to keep a variable tracking the current direction. On a change of direction you would need to invoke the iterator a second time.

Comment: Also, note you should add the items to the `ArrayList` and create the `ListIterator` after all items have been added to the ArrayList. If you add the items to the iterator then the iterator is already pointing at the last item. So when you click the "Next" button nothing happens. You have to go to the previous first, which is not intuitive.

Comment: Check out my comment to the original question for a simpler(?) solution.

Comment: @camickr I can't resist playing a guessing game here: it might be that the whole point of the assignment is to get aquainted with listIterator - if so, modifying the list via its iterator might be part of it. Also, I don't think it sooo unattractive to use iterator api for moving the cursor along the list - from the UX perspective it could be nicely implemented by en/disabling the corresponding button based on hasNext/-Previous in the next step of learning :) Just a thought ..

Comment: @kleopatra *it might be that the whole point of the assignment* - which is why I attempted to explain the problem and give the solution along with an alternative approach. Both approaches allow the OP to enable/disable the buttons, if desired. I also included the "?" with my comment to let the OP decide which approach they think is simpler.

Comment: @camickr we don't disagree, basically :) I simply didn't go as far as you in the explanation (first comment to the question), because the api doc is rather explicit on what happens (f.i. on add) - yours is certainly more helpful